# Cassandra - Limiting Table Size

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to limit the size of a table in Cassandra, by 'fair means or foul'? So either through the actual expected usage of Cassandra (I can't find anything in the docs) or by something a bit more hacky, like setting disk quotas for the locations storing SSTables or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

By design, C* will vary the amount of disk space used, eg. during compaction, saving key/row caches to disk, index files, bloom filters, snapshots etc (all config dependant) so it may not just be the data you've inserted that you need to account for. What should be included/excluded from this hard limit?

There's no C* feature to do what you need so using it probably isn't a good fit for your use case.

As for the disk quotas - try it. See what happens when the limit is reached. I expect (although don't know for sure) that C* will throw an exception and shutdown. Your nodes will probably fall like dominoes as each one reaches its quota or your client will choke when read/write consistency can't be met.

Comment: It's of note that one can monitor the size of a partition of a table on a given node using `nodetool`. You could aggregate this across nodes in a cluster to estimate the total size of a table, but not to limit it.